# ¿Es posible prevenir que un job vuelva a ejecutarse mientras aun continue realizando tareas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

Necesito crear un Job en sql server que se ejecute cada 5 minutos. El job debe ejecutar un procedimiento de almacenado que verifica unos registros en la base de datos, los cuales, dependiendo de su estado deberá realizar la ejecución de otros procedimientos de almacenados. El problema es que he notado que algunos procesos toman un poco mas de tiempo y quisiera saber, si es posible, indicarle al job de alguna manera, luego de su ejecución, que no continue ejecutándose sino hasta haber acabado de realizar todas las tareas que tiene suscritas.

Es decir, algo asi como:

1. ejecución del job
2. detener el job para que no vuelva a ejecutarse
3. ejecutar procedimientos de almacenado
   ...hacer tareas
4. cuando todas las tareas esten terminadas, habilitar nuevamente el job para que siga ejecutándose en los intervalos de tiempo programados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En SQL-Server los Jobs solamente pueden ejecutar una versión a la vez.
Quiere decir que si lo configuras para lanzarse cada 5 minutos, si tarda 4 no hay problema, cuando llegue el minuto 5 se volverá a lanzar, pero si dura 5' y 1'', la llamada que debería haber un segundo antes se queda en espera hasta el siguiente múltiplo de 5.
Compruébalo por si acaso, si... por ejemplo tu Job tarda 3 minutos ponlo cada 5 temporalmente y verás como es así. 
Luego... no te olvides de dejarlo a 5 como querías.